# ssh will ask password anyway

Tags: ssh, passwords

intermediate user here (at least I hope so !)

sorry if this is redundant but I looked for hours and I cant find !

I'm trying to install a server on a cheap laptop (Atom) running Ubuntu 10.04. I generated a RSA key something like 1 year ago (that's why I made a new post, I would like to use the same private key that I use for the other server I use to connect to). The public key is on the server in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys, the private key is in .ssh on my local laptop, but when I connect over ssh, it keeps asking me the password.

any hepl would be very appreciated,

thanks a lot,

Will

Comment: Re: shiplu.mokadd.im note, I'll assume you have generated a key without a passphrase. If that's true, then try connecting with verbose mode `ssh -vv ...`. Verbose mode will let you know the various connection attempts and why they are failing.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.rebol.com/docs/ssh-auto-login.html

Start with this. Then remember that the key that is generated is the unique key you would want to have on any machines you're trying to login to. Hope that helps.